# discord.js Linkfilter TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of null

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have an error on my linkfilter system. Something with the roles is not working.

https://sourceb.in/pwvz5xjucp

This is the error I get:

```
(node:12236) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of null
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\eFhii\Desktop\Venetic eSports\development_discord\index.js:134:24)
    at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\eFhii\Desktop\Venetic eSports\development_discord\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\eFhii\Desktop\Venetic eSports\development_discord\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\eFhii\Desktop\Venetic eSports\development_discord\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\eFhii\Desktop\Venetic eSports\development_discord\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\eFhii\Desktop\Venetic eSports\development_discord\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\eFhii\Desktop\Venetic eSports\development_discord\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\eFhii\Desktop\Venetic eSports\development_discord\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:825:20)
    at Receiver.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.dataMessage (C:\Users\eFhii\Desktop\Venetic eSports\development_discord\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:437:14)
    at Receiver.getData (C:\Users\eFhii\Desktop\Venetic eSports\development_discord\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:367:17)
    at Receiver.startLoop (C:\Users\eFhii\Desktop\Venetic eSports\development_discord\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:143:22)
    at Receiver._write (C:\Users\eFhii\Desktop\Venetic eSports\development_discord\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:78:10)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:403:12)
```

Comment: Your error says the error occures from line 24, which is an empty line. You say the error is on line 17 in your sourcebin, line 17 is just an array definition. Are you sure you have the right code? Also please post your code in codeblock form in your question, not on a bin site

Comment: Yes its the right code. My index.js contains other codes. But I dont want to show them here. Thats why I copied the linkfilter code and pasted it into soucebin. The error is the error from the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As message.member returns [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) in this case there is no member.
What does that mean? that means someone messaged bot in private chat (DMs)
To solve this just ignore messages if it is not in a server:
`if(!message.guild) return;`
so your code will be something like this:\

```js
//Linkfilter
bot.on("message", async message => {
    if(!message.guild) return;
    const mongo = require('./mongo')
    const warnSchema = require('./models/warn-schema')
```

Comment: Well.. thank you! It helped me c: Its working now without problems.